# Scan a Section using Asprise OCR

Tags: c#, ocr, picturebox

I downloaded the sample of OCR made by Asprise. I liked it because it's very fast. There is only i little problem in the sample: When you import a picture, you can't select the part of the photo you want to convert to TXT. How can I view the image in a pictureBox and select (I think using two Point) the part to scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you will have to do is create a crop like tool. Assuming your image is in a picture box control, it'll look like this:

```
private bool _isSelecting;
private Rectangle _selectionRectangle;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _isSelecting = false;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        _selectionRectangle = new Rectangle(e.X, e.Y, 0, 0);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        _isSelecting = true;
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        _selectionRectangle = new Rectangle(_selectionRectangle.Left, _selectionRectangle.Top,
            e.X - _selectionRectangle.Left, e.Y - _selectionRectangle.Top);
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isSelecting)
        return;
    using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _selectionRectangle);
    }
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image))
    {
        if (_selectionRectangle.Width + _selectionRectangle.X > pictureBox1.Image.Width)
            _selectionRectangle.Width = pictureBox1.Image.Width - _selectionRectangle.X;
        if (_selectionRectangle.Height + _selectionRectangle.Y > pictureBox1.Image.Height)
            _selectionRectangle.Height = pictureBox1.Image.Height - _selectionRectangle.Y;

        var selectedBmp = bmp.Clone(_selectionRectangle, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        pictureBox1.Image = selectedBmp;
    }
    _isSelecting = false;
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

This code will allow you to drag a box around the area you want to select, then it'll replace the old image with the selected area of the old image. Then all you have to do is pass the new image onto your OCR software.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to make a new image for the performance sake. [Asprise OCR](http://asprise.com/royalty-free-library/ocr-api-for-java-csharp-vb.net.html) allow you to pass the area you'd like to OCR as parameters. For example:

```
string s = ocr.Recognize("img.jpg", -1, 0, 0, 400, 200,
   AspriseOCR.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, AspriseOCR.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
```

The above code instructs the OCR engine to perform OCR on the top left part of the image with width 400 pixels and height 200 pixels.

For more details, visit [C# VB.NET OCR Developer's Guide: Perform OCR On Part Of The Image](http://asprise.com/ocr/docs/html/asprise-ocr-library-csharp-vb.net-component.html#perform-ocr-on-part-of-the-image)